# Rails: Sending a view to delayed job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have a Rails view that performs a lot of very expensive nested queries. I'm looking to throw the heavy lifting into delayed job, spit out a cache file, and poll for said cache by ajax.

I do this sort of thing quite a lot, but typically I cache the query (instead of the whole view). In this instance, it'd take a helluva long time to write up the SQL to include everything needed, and I'd rather just render a whole partial template into delayed_job.

...And that's where the fun starts. I'm getting a lot of errors, particularly related to form_helpers, devise authentication, etc etc etc. In short, does anyone have any suggestions for either:

- A simple way to render a partial view (or return render of an action) in delayed job?
- A simple way to achieve the above, without writing out what would be one helluva convoluted SQL/ActiveRecord query?

Any ideas appreciated - many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, rendering the view itself it possible in a relatively easy way, just have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.amberbit.com/blog/render-views-and-partials-outside-controllers-in-rails-3).

However, I would study the code and setup to be able to answer the following questions:

1. Is it possible to optimize the system to avoid delayed rendering at all? Checking your DB indexing, playing with queries and DB settings might turn what have been seen impossible into real scenario.
2. Might it be enough to harvest the data in delayed job, serialize it as json and perform presentation on the browser side? By doing so you leave youself a self way back if once you discover the bottleneck and decide to move processing back to webapp.
3. Might pre-computing (using tables of simplier structure) help? You can always populate these table in background or even employ triggers and have you app work in a straight manner.

Hope anything of the above helps :)